# Stop QGIS opening multiple taskbar items?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have QGIS pinned to my taskbar, right clicking shows that it's named "QGIS Desktop 3.8.2". When I run it and open projects some of them open a new taskbar item called "QGIS 3". This also happens when I open an attribute table or layout view.

When I open their properties they are the same except for the "Start in:" field:
[image]

They also show different Recent projects when I right click on them.

When I installed the latest version of QGIS I made sure to do a clean install and remove all previous versions. When I go to Help > About they are all running 3.8.2.

How do I stop duplicate taskbar items from opening?

EDIT: I am using Windows 10 but this issue has been around since before I updated from Windows 7

Comment: Hi, which version of Windows are you using - it might help someone answer your question?

Comment: @ian - Windows 10, I should have included that, I'll edit it into the question. However this issue has been happening since before I updated from Windows 7